# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have made a separate component which can be considered as a child which I am calling in a parent component. While calling the component by importing it properly I am facing this issue

I have tried to create a separate method in order to call the component and then call the method which will bring the functionality of the component but no luck.

Below is the child component named as GlobalHeaderHelpLabel.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Popover } from "@salesforce/design-system-react";
import { GlobalHeaderHelp } from "@salesforce/design-system-react";

const ipsum = "Lorem";

class GlobalHeaderHelpLabel extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GlobalHeaderHelp
        popover={
          <Popover
            ariaLabelledby="help-heading"
            body={
              <div>
                <h2 className="slds-text-heading_small" id="help-heading">
                  Help and Training
                </h2>
                {ipsum}
              </div>
            }
            id="header-help-popover-id"
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default GlobalHeaderHelpLabel;
```

Below is the parent component to which I am calling this child and facing the error named as GlobalHeaderLabel.js :

```
import React from "react";
import GlobalHeaderHelpLabel from "./GlobalHeaderHelpLabel";

class GlobalHeaderLabel extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <GlobalHeaderHelpLabel />;
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Below is the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: `GlobalHeaderHelp` is not imported. So is `Popover`

Comment: @Rajesh they both are imported but for the sake of putting code simple on stack overflow removed them from this snippet but now I think I should add those in order for no confusion.

Comment: almost always it means either `import` is missing or named import is used instead default(or in opposite)

Comment: @skyboyer can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: probably you have to import either `Popover` or `GlobalHeaderHelp` without curly braces 
 https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: You are importing Popover and GlobalHeaderHelp  from '@salesforce/design-system-react'. You can check documentation once here https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/ to see if you are importing correctly.

Comment: @MahendraPratap by doing according to the documentation which is stated in the given link:https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-headers/

I am facing this issue while importing

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

so the workaround I found was the one I did

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Popover Component is exported as default. Change:

```
import {Popover} from '@salesforce/design-system-react';
```

to:

```
import Popover from '@salesforce/design-system-react';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me after running around from pillar to post. A giant FU for idiotic TS spec which allows this to happen: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#1132-import-declarations and no thanks to shitty ReactJS eco system that thinks that the error message is descriptive enough (and no way to debug).